# how to check axios get function called or not in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, axios, react-hooks-testing-library

I am trying to test below function or in other words I am trying to write unit test cases of below function.But I am getting error `_axios.default.get.mockResolvedValueOnce is not a function`

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
export default () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("https://5os4e.csb.app/data.json");
    setState(res.data);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await fetchData();
    })();
  }, []);

  return [state];
};
```

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-jepsen-5os4e?file=/src/usetabData.test.js

I write unit test case like that

```
import useTabData from "./useTabData";
import { act, renderHook, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import mockAxios from "axios";
describe("use tab data", () => {
  afterEach(cleanup);
  it("fetch tab data", async () => {
    mockAxios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({
      data: {
        name: "hello"
      }
    });
    await act(async () => renderHook(() => useTabData()));
    expect(mockAxios.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: `import mockAxios from "axios";` looks to be the default export from axios. Did you mean to import *some* mocked version of it instead?

Comment: I am trying to mock axios .is there any other way >

Comment: see i created `__mocks___` folder

Comment: @DrewReese did you get my point ?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I prefer to keep my tests with the components and mock imports on demand where necessary, so I've minimal experience with a `__mocks__` and `__tests__` directories. Looks like your issue has been resolved though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code sandbox doesn't support manual mocks as far as I know.
However, your `__mock__` is placed in wrong directory structure. It should be a sibling of `node_module`.

Having said that, easiest way is to use https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter

```
import useTabData from "./useTabData";
import { act, renderHook, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import axios from "axios";
import MockAxiosAdapter from "axios-mock-adapter";

const mockAxios = new MockAxiosAdapter(axios);
afterEach(() => {
    cleanup();// this is not needed . its done by testing library after each.
    mockAxios.reset();
  });
describe("use tab data", () => {
  it("fetch tab data", async () => {
    mockAxios.onGet(200, { data: { test: "123" } }); // response code and object.
    const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useTabData());
    const [value] = result.current;
    // assert value
    // assert the axios call by using history object
  });
});
```

You can use history to assert:  https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter#history

Comment: could you please I tried different way to check `setState` is called or not https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-meadow-9l41z?file=/src/useTabData.test.js

Comment: sorry. This diverges from question or issue you have. create a diff issue. Your current code has moxios but there seems to be other errors in mocking and usage of `React.useState` which is incorrect. You can start from what I have posted above and try from there.